# SPOJ "CENCRY" Code gettingTLE

Tags: c++, time

[CENCRY](http://www.spoj.com/problems/CENCRY/)

problem as described in spoj, here is my source code, my source code has order O(strlen) but still giving Time Limit Exceeded, any help in logic.

```
int main()
{
    int T,pos,loc;
    cin>>T;
    char str[50000], vowel[]= {"aeiou"}, consonant[] = {"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"};
    int hash[26]={0,0,1,2,1,3,4,5,2,6,7,8,9,10,3,11,12,13,14,15,4,16,17,18,19,20};

    while(T--)
    {
    int hashC[26]={0};
    cin >> str;
    for(int i = 0;i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
        int ch=str[i]-97;
        pos = hash[ch];
        loc = hashC[ch];
        switch(ch)
        {
        case 0:
        case 4:
        case 8:
        case 14:
        case 20:
            cout<<consonant[(loc*5+pos)%21];
            break;
        default:
            cout<<vowel[(loc*21+pos)%5];
            break;
        }
        hashC[ch]++;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this is c++, why not use `string` rather than `char []`?

Comment: char array is faster than string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using std::cin and std::cout try to use scanf and printf -these functions may make you program to be much more faster expecialy when a lot of data is given on stdin.
Besides...
You should use srlen ONCE and write an output to some variable the use it on the "for" loop.

BTW.
You should give us link to your task becouse your algorithm might be wrong at all and even my previous advices won't be enougt to solve your problem.

Comment: This is not true if you specify [std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) at the top of main